# Python Pandas DataFrames: Dropping entire rows if one entry is unwanted

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to delete an entire row of a Pandas DataFrame if that row has a particular entry in one of its columns. Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. In the DataFrame below, I'd like to get rid of rows 'b' and 'd' because they have unwanted entries in column 'C':

```
unwanted_df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['aA', 'bA', 'cA', 'dA'],
                               'B' : ['aB', 'bB', 'cB', 'dB'],
                               'C' : ['aC', 'unwanted_1', 'cC', 'unwanted_2'],
                               'D' : ['aD', 'bD', 'cD', 'dD']}, 
                               index = ['a','b','c','d'])
unwanted_df
```

Here's what that DataFrame looks like:

[Original DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okVk3.png)

I tried defining a new DataFrame with the dropped rows using Boolean operators like so:

```
dropped_unwanted_df = \
unwanted_df.drop(unwanted_df[(unwanted_df['C'] == 'unwanted_1') | 
                             (unwanted_df['C'] == 'unwanted_2')], axis = 1)
```

However, the output is not what's expected.

```
dropped_unwanted_df
```

Here's what I get:

[Unexpected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkDNG.png)

I wrote another little code that produces what I would have expected:

```
expected_df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['aA', 'cA'],
                           'B' : ['aB', 'cB'],
                           'C' : ['aC', 'cC'],
                           'D' : ['aD', 'cD']}, 
                           index = ['a','c'])
```

expected_df

This is the output I would've liked:

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5n6gN.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
expected_df = unwanted_df.loc[(unwanted_df['C']!='unwanted_1')&(unwanted_df['C']!='unwanted_2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use **`isin`**:

```
unwanted_df.loc[~unwanted_df.isin(['unwanted_1', 'unwanted_2']).any(1)]

    A   B   C   D
a  aA  aB  aC  aD
c  cA  cB  cC  cD
```

Or if you want to just check column `C`:

```
unwanted_df.loc[~unwanted_df.C.isin(['unwanted_1', 'unwanted_2'])]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!
The issue is that this solution deletes *column* 'C' when my goal was to delete *rows* 'b' and 'c'. I'd like to delete the rows with the unwanted entries not the columns. How would you recommend doing that?
Thanks!

Comment: @user10200596 can you double check my answer, I misread your question initially, but now it should do what you want.